# accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer

Tags: c#, properties

I have the folowing class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace Framework
{
    public class OracleProvider
    {
        private OdbcConnection db { get; private set; }
        private String dbUsername = Settings.Default.Username;
        private String dbPassword = Settings.Default.Password;

        public OracleProvider()
        {
            connect();
        }

        public void connect()
        { 
            db = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=CTIR; UID="+dbUsername+";PWD="+dbPassword+";");    
        }        
    }
}
```

Now I get the following error:

> Error 11: The accessibility modifier of the 'Framework.OracleProvider.db.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'Framework.OracleProvider.db'

I've been looking at similar questions but haven't really found an answer.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? I really want to learn.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
private OdbcConnection db { get; private set; }
```

Assuming you really want both the getter and setter to be private, this should be:

```
private OdbcConnection db { get; set; }
```

The setter is *already* `private`, as that's the accessibility of the overall property.

Alternatively, if you want the getter to be non-private and the setter to be private, you need to specify some other modifier, e.g.

```
internal OdbcConnection db { get; set; }
```

Basically, if you're going to specify an access modifier on the `get;` or `set;` part of a property, it has to be more restrictive than it would otherwise be.

From section 10.7.2 of the C# specification:

> The *accessor-modifier* must declare an accessibility that is strictly more restrictive than the declared accessibility of the property or indexer itself. To be precise:
>
> - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of `public`, the *accessor-modifier* may be either `protected internal`, `internal`, `protected`, or `private`.
> - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of `protected internal`, the *accessor-modifier* may be either `internal`, `protected`, or `private`.
> - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of `internal` or `protected`, the *accessor-modifier* must be `private`.
> - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of `private`, no *accessor-modifier* may be used.

(As an aside, if it's private for both reading and writing, it would probably be better just to use a field. Most of the benefits of using a property are only present if it's exposed beyond the current class. And if you *do* keep it as a property, consider renaming it to follow normal .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: A common pattern is to make the setter private but the getter public/protected in order to make the property read-only, might be worth adding this to the answer just for completeness

Comment: @Charleh: I've already done so, giving an example of an internal getter.

Comment: Yeah it took about 5 minutes for my comment to post by which time you'd already updated :)

Comment: i am a java developer originally what is internal and how does it compare to private, protected and public?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: That's a different question - and one best answered with a bit of research first :) (Search for "msdn internal c#" and you're likely to get your answer.)

Comment: @JonSkeet  Do we need to remember the combination as mentioned in the specification? The reason I ask is if I use internal protective in either way gives me error. Which one is more restrictive? Looks this type of logic does not make sense, just need to remember the combination.

Comment: @RotatingWheel: I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like you should ask a new question explaining what you're actually trying to achieve - I can't tell from your comment.

Comment: I think it's a bit odd you can't use a protected internal accessor for an otherwise internal property though. Isn't protected internal more restrictive than just internal?

Comment: @Ecchi-Alex: No, it's *less* restrictive than `internal`. "Access limited to this program or classes derived from this class". It's the union, not the intersection. (It's possible that there'll be a new modifier combination in C# 7 for the intersection.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, my bad. I thought it was limited to assembly AND derived classes. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Well, the error tells all the *information required*:

> *accessibility modifier ... accessor must be more restrictive than the property ...*

```
  private OdbcConnection db { // <- property as whole is "private"
    get; 
    private set; // <- accessor (set) is explictly declared as "private" 
  }
```

So you can do either

```
  // property as a whole is "public", but "set" accessor is "private"
  // and so the accessor is more restrictive than the property
  public OdbcConnection db { // <- property as whole is "public"
    get; 
    private set; // <- accessor is "private" (more restrictive than "public")
  }
```

Or

```
  private OdbcConnection db { 
    get; 
    set; // <- just don't declare accessor modifier
  }
```