# The accessibility of the 'GetServiceCafe.EntityCafe.hasil.get' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

My problem is when I try to debug my program I get error "The Property or indexer 'GetServiceCafe.EntityCafe.hasil' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor inaccessible"

I am trying to fix it with this [accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226718/accessor-must-be-more-restrictive-than-the-property-or-indexer) but in my case the main problem is `get` not set, I try to change `get` into public but still get this error.

EntityCafe.cs :

```
namespace GetServiceCafe
{
    class EntityCafe
    {
        List<EntityData> hasil { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityData
    {
        public int ID_Transaksi { get; set; }
        public string Nama_Pemesan { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Detail_Pesanan { get; set; }
        public int Total_Biaya { get; set; }
        public string Jenis_Transaksi { get; set; }
        public string Cabang { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs :

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("myTable");
table.Columns.Add("ID_Transaksi", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Nama Pemesan", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Detail Pesanan", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Total_Biaya", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Jenis_Transaksi", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Cabang", typeof(string));

foreach (var obj in dataPengiriman.hasil)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();//empty row
    row[0] = obj.id_transaksi.ToString();
    row[1] = obj.nama_pemesan.ToString();
    row[2] = obj.detail_pesanan.ToString();
    row[3] = obj.total_biaya.ToString();
    row[4] = obj.jenis_transaksi.ToString();
    row[5] = obj.cabang.ToString();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is inaccessible since it's not `public`, you can make the get `public`:

```
public class EntityCafe 
{
    public List<EntityData> hasil { get; private set; } // it should be Hasil 
}
```

Note that the class must also be `public` if you want to create an instance from the form.